# How to get rid of `?` in URL when no parameters exist?

Tags: php

I have the following rule which checks if the url contains any parameters that start with `p2`:

```
function unparse_url($parsed_url) {
  $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
  $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
  $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';
  $user     = isset($parsed_url['user']) ? $parsed_url['user'] : '';
  $pass     = isset($parsed_url['pass']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['pass']  : '';
  $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
  $path     = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
  $query    = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . trim($parsed_url['query'], '&') : '';
  $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
  return "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment";
}

function strip_query($url, $query_to_strip) {
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  $parsed['query'] = preg_replace('/(^|&)'.$query_to_strip.'[^&]*/', '', $parsed['query']);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}

$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$new_url = (strip_query($url, 'p2'));

# redirect  if url contains anything that starts with p2 

$filtered = array_filter(array_keys($_GET), function($k) {
    return strpos($k, 'p2') === 0;
});

if ( !empty($filtered) ) {
    header ("Location: $new_url");
}
else {

}
```

If a url contain any `p2*` parameters, a redirect will be made to the same page without these parameters.

Example:

`domain.com/?a=3&p2=1`

will redirect to

`domain.com/?a=3`

However, with the current rule, if the original URL is:

`domain.com/?p2=1`

Then it will redirect to:

`domain.com/?`

But since it is meaningless, I want that in this case it will redirect to:

`domain.com/`

How can it be done?

Comment: you mean [this](http://url.thephpleague.com/4.0/uri/manipulation/query/)? need to check it out. what advantages does it have over using my code though?

Answer (score 1):

Like @dontfight i would suggest to use mod_rewrite but if you prefer PHP you could use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) before you do the redirect

```
rtrim($url, '?');
```

With your code you could use like this

```
$filtered = array_filter(array_keys($_GET), function($k) {
    return strpos($k, 'p2') === 0;
});

$new_url_trim = rtrim($new_url, '?');

if ( !empty($filtered) ) {
    header ("Location: $new_url_trim");
}
else {

}
```

Comment: I do of course want to keep the `?` in case that the original url contains other paramers, such as in case of `domain.com/?a=3&p2=1` would it keep it?

Comment: @rockyraw with rtrim it will remove the ? mark if only it is the last character :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to remove query parameters:

1. Parse the URL to separate it into the scheme, path, and query
2. Parse the query string into an array
3. Unset the parameter within the array
4. Recreate the URL

Example:

```
<?php

function removeQuery($url, $param) {
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);

    unset($query[$param]);

    $parsed['scheme'] .= '://';
    $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($query);
    if (!empty($parsed['query']))
        $parsed['path'] .= '?';

    return implode($parsed);
}

echo removeQuery('http://domain.com/?a=3&p2=1', 'a') . "\n";
echo removeQuery('http://domain.com/?a=3&p2=1', 'p2') . "\n";
echo removeQuery('http://domain.com/?p2=1', 'p2');
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/b12371bc9e9c41):

```
http://domain.com/?p2=1
http://domain.com/?a=3
http://domain.com/
```

---

Also I noticed that you wanted to remove `p2` if it occurs anywhere in the string, so here's another version designed to do just that:

```
<?php

function removeP2($url) {
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);

    foreach ($query as $key => $value)
        if (strpos($key, 'p2') === 0)
            unset($query[$key]);

    $parsed['scheme'] .= '://';
    $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($query);
    if (!empty($parsed['query']))
        $parsed['path'] .= '?';

    return implode($parsed);
}

echo removeP2('http://domain.com/?a=3&p2=1') . "\n";
echo removeP2('http://domain.com/?a=3&p2sks=1') . "\n";
echo removeP2('http://domain.com/?p2=1');
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/e24bf5b175e9ee):

```
http://domain.com/?a=3
http://domain.com/?a=3
http://domain.com/
```

---

Now to get it to redirect, you already know how to redirect:

```
header("Location: " . removeP2('http://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]));
```

Comment: You got me kinda lost, basically I don't want to echo the new url, I want to redirect to it. and the code can't include any reference to `domain.com`, it needs to be independant, so I'm using `http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`

Comment: I've provided you with a function to convert your URL. `header("Location: " . removeP2("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"));`. Just plug in your independent url into the function, and you'll get the url back without P2, and then you can redirect to it.

Comment: Ok thanks, this works too. Is it better to use your code? simply because it's more neat? or will it have better server performance as well? are there any differences with the final results?

Comment: Looking at the original code, it looks like you took a lot into consideratiom. However fragments aren't detected by the server so there's no need to check if it's empty or not. So it will be faster because I'm completely ignoring fragments, but only a benchmark will confirm this. There should be no differences in the final results (unless fragments are involved).

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has bothered to tell you what's wrong...

Your problem is that your `strip_query()` function always sets `$url["query"]` to a value, even if that value is an empty string:

```
$parsed['query'] = preg_replace('/(^|&)'.$query_to_strip.'[^&]*/', '', $parsed['query']);
```

When your `unparse_url()` function gets the URL, it's checking that array index using `isset()` which always passes:

```
$query    = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . trim($parsed_url['query'], '&') : '';
```

Instead of checking with `isset()` you could use `empty()`, which will return false if the value is unset *or* if it's an empty string:

```
$query    = !empty($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . trim($parsed_url['query'], '&') : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

if [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is available, this can be done without php code.

Comment: I don't want to use `htaccess`, as I plan to store in a session the data of the `p2` parameters.

Comment: FYI: .`htaccess` got nothing with mod_rewrite. It;s the apache way of setting some things at runtime when you cannot access server config. But if you can there's no need for `.htaccess` if you do not need it

Comment: can I use `mod_rewrite` and at the same time, store in a session the data that the `p2` parameter contained originally?

Comment: Can Anyone answer this sub-question?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, as mod_rewrite is from Apache and session is from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, its a comment, but its a bit long.

Why are you so keen to strip this variable from the URL? What harm has it ever done to you that you must go to such lengths to eradicate its existence? And why not just...

```
unset($_GET['p2']);
```

> But since it is meaningless,

In what way?

I can see some merit in the `unparse_url($parsed_url)` function and if you fix the bugs (hint: try some test cases with usernames and/or passwords) then it's reasonably well structured - but the subsequent code for manipulating the data is a messy mix of regular expression string splicing - which is not the right way to deal with such structured data - PHP has functions for that.

But the worst bit is then injecting another complete RTT to resolve the URL.

You are better than this rockyraw!

Comment: haha, well, I just wanted to make the url look natural. I didn't come up with this code, i've just constructed it from various questions that I've been asking here. I'm not a php developer (so I'm not sure what's `unset`, but note that this need to work on any parameter that starts with `p2` though, like `p2_hello`). my only goal was to be able to strip parameters from the url, store them in a session first, and destroy the evidence on the client-side by making a redirect.